# What elasticsearch version does Spring boot 1.5.9 support?

Tags: java, elasticsearch, spring-boot, versioning, spring-data-elasticsearch

I try to figure out what the newest version of elasticsearch can i use with the newest  Spring boot release (currently it is 1.5.9). 
I've found [matrix](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-elasticsearch/wiki/Spring-Data-Elasticsearch---Spring-Boot---version-matrix), but seems that it is out to date. 
Also I've found that spring data elasticsearch 3.0.2.RELEASE supports 5+ elasticsearch. 
So the questions are:

1. Can we use Spring boot  1.5.9 with spring data elasticsearch 3.0.2.RELEASE?
2. if not, what is it the newest elasticsearch version that we can use with  spring boot 1.5.9 (with spring data)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

answering your questions:

1. Unfortunately the spring data elasticseach 3.X requires the Spring Boot 2.X (see also this answer: [Elasticsearch 5.x Repository Java Spring Boot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44956426/elasticsearch-5-x-repository-java-spring-boot/44968109#44968109))
2. With Spring Boot 1.X you could use latest 2.X spring data elasticsearch and with that you could use Elasticsearch 2.X.X version in this case.

I assume that you are aware that there is no 3.X and 4.X version of Elasticsearch - from versioning reasons they moved from 2.X to 5.X.